# Rellenar Desconocidos

Tags: r

Tengo estos datos:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
k <- data.table(name = rep(c("Mun1","Mun2","Mun3","Mun4"),, each = 5),
                year = rep(2015:2019, times = 4),
                values = c(19, 19, 18, 500, NA, 44, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 7, NA, 200, NA))
    
    k[order(k$year,)] ->k


    name year values
 1: Mun1 2015     19
 2: Mun2 2015     44
 3: Mun3 2015     NA
 4: Mun4 2015     NA
 5: Mun1 2016     19
 6: Mun2 2016     NA
 7: Mun3 2016     NA
 8: Mun4 2016      7
 9: Mun1 2017     18
10: Mun2 2017     NA
11: Mun3 2017     NA
12: Mun4 2017     NA
13: Mun1 2018    500
14: Mun2 2018      6
15: Mun3 2018     NA
16: Mun4 2018    200
17: Mun1 2019     NA
18: Mun2 2019     NA
19: Mun3 2019      1
20: Mun4 2019     NA
```

Quiero rellenar los desconocidos por el valor del año siguiente según municipio.
Por ejemplo, el NA de Mun4 año 2015 se rellena con un 7 (Mun4 año 2016).

El NA de Mun3 año 2015 no se rellena con el año 2016 porque no hay datos, pasa al año siguiente, donde tampoco hay datos, pasa al siguiente y así sucesivamente hasta llegar al último año que hay un 1.

Básicamente el código para hacer eso es este:

```
k %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric,funs(ifelse(is.na(.),na.locf(.,fromLast=TRUE),.)))
```

El problema es que el último año (2019) se rellena con los datos del primer año (2015), digamos que le da la vuelta a los datos.
Me gustaría que al llegar al 2019 no rellene hacia abajo,sino hacia arriba, que coja los datos del 2018, 2017 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que lo puedes conseguir con `fill(na.omit("values"), .direction = "updown")`

```r
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

k <- data.table(
  name = rep(c("Mun1", "Mun2", "Mun3", "Mun4"), , each = 5),
  year = rep(2015:2019, times = 4),
  values = c(19, 19, 18, 500, NA, 44, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 7, NA, 200, NA)
)

k[order(k$year, )] -> k

# Ejemplo usado
withzoo <- k %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(is.na(.),
                                    zoo::na.locf(., fromLast = TRUE), .
  ))) %>%
  pull(values) %>%
  as_tibble_col(column_name = "withzoo")
#> `mutate_if()` ignored the following grouping variables:
#> * Column `name`
#> Warning: `funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.
#> Please use a list of either functions or lambdas: 
#> 
#>   # Simple named list: 
#>   list(mean = mean, median = median)
#> 
#>   # Auto named with `tibble::lst()`: 
#>   tibble::lst(mean, median)
#> 
#>   # Using lambdas
#>   list(~ mean(., trim = .2), ~ median(., na.rm = TRUE))
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.

k <- k %>% bind_cols(withzoo)

k %>%
  arrange(name, year) %>%
  # Creo una variable alternativa para comparar
  mutate(test = values) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  # With fill
  fill(na.omit("test"), .direction = "updown")
#> # A tibble: 20 x 5
#> # Groups:   name [4]
#>    name   year values withzoo  test
#>    <chr> <int>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Mun1   2015     19      19    19
#>  2 Mun1   2016     19      19    19
#>  3 Mun1   2017     18      18    18
#>  4 Mun1   2018    500     500   500
#>  5 Mun1   2019     NA      19   500
#>  6 Mun2   2015     44      44    44
#>  7 Mun2   2016     NA       6     6
#>  8 Mun2   2017     NA       6     6
#>  9 Mun2   2018      6       6     6
#> 10 Mun2   2019     NA      44     6
#> 11 Mun3   2015     NA       1     1
#> 12 Mun3   2016     NA       1     1
#> 13 Mun3   2017     NA       1     1
#> 14 Mun3   2018     NA       1     1
#> 15 Mun3   2019      1       1     1
#> 16 Mun4   2015     NA       7     7
#> 17 Mun4   2016      7       7     7
#> 18 Mun4   2017     NA     200   200
#> 19 Mun4   2018    200     200   200
#> 20 Mun4   2019     NA       7   200
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Me cuesta ver estos problemas sin pensar en un proceso iterativo, así que esta es una solución más clásica, básicamente, cuando se encuentra un `NA` vamos hacia adelante buscando el primer valor no `NA` y si no lo encontramos, traemos el primero, pero de la parte de atrás. Ejemplo:

```
get_non_na <- function(posicion_na, v) {
  if (!is.na(v[posicion_na]))
    return(v[posicion_na])
  
  longitud_v <- length(v)
  adelante <- v[posicion_na:longitud_v]
  
  reemplazo <- adelante[which(!is.na(adelante))][1]
  if (is.na(reemplazo)) {
    atras <- v[1:posicion_na]
    reemplazo <- rev(atras[which(!is.na(atras))])[1]
  }
  reemplazo
}

replace_nas <- function(x) {
  newv <- list()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    newv[[i]] <- get_non_na(i, x)
  }
  unlist(newv)
}

v <- c(19, 19, 18, 500, NA, 23, NA, NA)

eplace_nas(v)

[1]  19  19  18 500  23  23  23  23
```

Esto aplicado a tus datos sería algo así:

```
k %>%
  arrange(name, year) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(new_values = replace_nas(values))

# A tibble: 20 x 4
# Groups:   name [4]
   name   year values new_values
   <chr> <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 Mun1   2015     19         19
 2 Mun1   2016     19         19
 3 Mun1   2017     18         18
 4 Mun1   2018    500        500
 5 Mun1   2019     NA        500
 6 Mun2   2015     44         44
 7 Mun2   2016     NA          6
 8 Mun2   2017     NA          6
 9 Mun2   2018      6          6
10 Mun2   2019     NA          6
11 Mun3   2015     NA          1
12 Mun3   2016     NA          1
13 Mun3   2017     NA          1
14 Mun3   2018     NA          1
15 Mun3   2019      1          1
16 Mun4   2015     NA          7
17 Mun4   2016      7          7
18 Mun4   2017     NA        200
19 Mun4   2018    200        200
20 Mun4   2019     NA        200
```